# Prove that $d_\infty(f, g) = \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\}$ defines a metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof?

> Let $C[a,b]$ denote the set of all continuous functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $d_\infty:C[a,b] \times C[a,b] \longrightarrow [0, \infty)$ be given by
>
> $$d_\infty(x,y) = \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\}$$
>
> Prove that $d_\infty$ is a norm on $C[a,b]$

We can verify the properties of a metric:
\begin{eqnarray}
d(x, y) &\geq& 0 \\
d(x,y) = 0 &\iff& x = y \\
d(x,y)&=&d(y,x) \\
d(x,y)& \leq& d(x, z) + d(y, z)
\end{eqnarray}

(1) Suppose $f = g$.

Then, for all $x \in [a,b]$, $$f(x) = g(x)$$

But then, for all $x \in [a, b]$, $$|f(x)-g(x)|=0$$

So, $$\operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} = 0$$

Now, let $f, g \in C[a,b]$ with $$\operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} = 0$$

Then, for all $x \in [a,b]$, $$f(x) = g(x)$$

(if that were not the case, then there would exist an $x_0 \in [a, b]$ with $|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|>0$).

(2) \begin{eqnarray}
d_\infty(f, g) &=& \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\
&=& \operatorname{sup}\{|g(x)-f(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\
&=& d_\infty(g, f)
\end{eqnarray}

(3) Let $h \in C[a,b]$.

Then,
\begin{eqnarray}
d_\infty(f,g) &=& \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\
&=& \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-h(x)+h(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\
\end{eqnarray}

Also, for all $x \in [a, b]$, we have

$$|f(x)-h(x)+h(x)-g(x)| \leq |f(x)-h(x)|+|h(x)-g(x)|$$

So,

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-h(x)+h(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} &\leq& \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-h(x)|+|h(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\
&\leq& \operatorname{sup}\{|f(x)-h(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\ &&+ \operatorname{sup}\{|h(x)-g(x)|:x \in [a,b]\} \\
&=& d_\infty(f, h) + d_\infty(g, h) \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Looks good to me.